# What is the down arrow next to my username?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-interface

In the interface, up the very top, to the right I see the following:

Envelope, Username, Reputation, Down Arrow, Number

What does the number represent?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Hover with your mouse over it and look at the tooltip.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why it was displaying as an arrow before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming the "down arrow" is ●, which renders as a circle in my browser. This is a bronze badge, and the number to the right of it is the number that you have. In this case, you have 2.

Answer (score 2):

We now use CSS image sprites for this.